# UITableView crashes when adding 2 objects to an empty store, with sections (NSRangeException)

Tags: iphone, uitableview, core-data

UITableView crashes in endUpdate, called by the Managed Object Context "save" method, when:

1- The Core-Data Store is empty

2- The Fetched Result Controller is configured to show sections

3- Two managed objects (or more) have been added to the store

When I've searched this problem in google. I've found exactly matched error in [this post](http://openradar.appspot.com/7757591). 
It looks like a SDK bug.Is there a any solution to avoid this bug ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the [`SafeFetchedResultsController`](http://deusty.blogspot.com/2010/02/more-bugs-in-nsfetchedresultscontroller.html) subclass seems to resolve a number of crashes caused by problems in how `NSFetchedResultsController` manages updates to table views.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but I've resolve this problem like following :
in controllerDidChangeContent: methods, 

    @try {
        [tableView endUpdates];
    }
    @catch (NSException * e) {
        // remove table view from super view and create a new table view .. 
        return;
    }